# How get teamcity env params in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, teamcity

I have several build steps in teamcity which build and push docker image. How can I get env params from teamcity in `dockerfile`. Now `dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM python:3.8.9-slim-buster
ENV test24=2626
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "sh", "./app.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `--build-arg ARG_NAME=ARG_VALUE` options to the `docker build` command, and within the Dockerfile you then have an `ARG` defined to pickup the value. eg:

```
ARG ARG_VALUE=DEFAULT_ARG_VALUE_IF_NOT_SPECIFIED

LABEL com.stackoverflow.arg="${ARG_VALUE}"
```